# Can we use angular 2 library in angular 1 application?

Tags: angularjs, angular

There is a authentication library written for angular applications. But the library is not available for angularJS applications. Is there any way that we can use those libraries in angularJS applications? If yes that would be a great help.

Comment: As I know you can't use **angular2+** libraries in **angularjs** projects.

Comment: "No". Angular 2-based libraries *require* Angular 2-based API. There was a rather large shift between how Angular 2 works form it's predecessor.. now, depending on the library, and how much dicing one wants to/can do..

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular libraries in an AngularJS project is impossible.
This is not the same way to code, architecture and languages are different.

The solution is to "translate" library you want to use from Angular to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is two way bridge, so you can use AngularJS components in Angular apps and vice versa. Study [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) to find out more informations. I've never practiced "bridging" Angular and AngularJS applications and I don't know if it works. You should avoid such practices, but if there is no other way, you can try.

Such an operation requires Angular and AngularJS app preparation.

Answering your question: YES - I know it is possible if the application and library are properly designed. Documentation describes how to create hybrid applications(Angular + AngularJS)

Good luck :)